# Leaflet w/ React: Individual country color won't re-render when this.props updates, only when mouse-over happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have managed to make a Leaflet map where the color of each country changes dependent on an input I receive as `this.props.data` in this specific React component.

It will correctly display the countries and the initial color. However, this information is fed from the backend every minute. If `this.props.data` updates, the countries do not change color - Only if I hold the mouse over a specific country; then the color will actually change?

For reference, I import the countries in the React class from a file(essentially a JS database of countries) like this example: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/jydMqy

Here's my source code.

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import countries from './countries.js';


var Worldmap = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        if(!this.props.data)
            return <div> loading world map ..  </div>;

        let dataratio = this.props.data; // Props from main component
        let size = Object.keys(dataratio).length; // Do we have data?

        if(size > 1) { // If we do have data, ..

            let dataratioToArr = Object.keys(dataratio).map(data => [ data, dataratio[data]]); // Conv. map to multidimensional array

            let featuresArr = countries.features; // array of all countries in array features from countries.js

            for(let i = 0; i < featuresArr.length; i++) // i = 178(no. of countries)
                for(let j = 0; j < dataratioToArr.length; j++) // j = no. of countries we have with dataratio > 1 from backend
                    if(dataratioToArr[j][0] == featuresArr[i].id) // If ISO-3 compliant ID of country(f.e. "USA") matches, push a "data" property to countries.js
                        featuresArr[i].properties.data = dataratioToArr[j][1];
        }

        return(
            <div id="leafletmap" style={{width: "100%", height: "80%", border: "2px solid black" }} />
        )
    },

    componentDidMount : function() {
        let geolocation =  [];
        // Retrieve geoloc coordinates
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            let lat = position.coords.latitude;
            let lon = position.coords.longitude;

            if(lat != null && lon != null) // If we can get latitude and longitude, reset geolocation and push values.
                geolocation.length = 0;
            geolocation.push(lat, lon);
            if(!lat || !lon) // If we can't get latitude or longitude, set a default value.
                geolocation = [0,0];

            let map = L.map('leafletmap').setView(geolocation, 3); // ([coordinates], zoomlevel)

            let info = L.control();

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            info.update = function (props) {
                this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Data ratio</h4>' +  (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.data + ' ratio'
                        : 'Hover over a country');
            };

            info.addTo(map);


            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 90 ? '#4a1486' :
                    d > 75  ? '#6a51a3' :
                        d > 50  ? '#807dba' :
                            d > 25  ? '#9e9ac8' :
                                d > 15   ? '#bcbddc' :
                                    d > 5   ? '#dadaeb' :
                                        d > 1   ? '#f2f0f7' :
                                            '#D3D3D3'; // Default color of data doesn't exist or is 0.
            }


            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.data)
                };
            }

            function highlightFeature(e) {
                let layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                });

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }

            let geojson;

            function resetHighlight(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });
            }


            geojson = L.geoJson(countries, { // from import
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

            let legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                let div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [1, 5, 15, 25, 50, 75, 90],
                    labels = [],
                    from, to;

                for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    from = grades[i];
                    to = grades[i + 1];

                    labels.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

                div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);
        });

    }
});

export default Worldmap
```

I had this `componentDidMount` as `getInitialState` to begin with; but I changed to `componentDidMount` since this should trigger a re-rendering of the component upon data change. The documentation states `If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.` - that doens't really happen in my code. Maybe I am misunderstanding it?

I could understand if the component never re-rendered, but it's super strange that it does if there's a mouseover event on the individual country(f.e. I hold over USA, and the color value will change to the correct one if it changed, but not until that happens(or refresh of entire site))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're conflating two different render concepts into one. When using React it is designed to control the render process; if you introduce another library which manages rendering then you can run into issues.

React is designed to render based on the following formula: view = f(data), in other words your view is a function of your data. In React, data is expressed through either Props or State. You are not using React to manage props or state in this case, you are using 'leaflet'. You will need to decide whether you want to use React or Leaflet to control rendering, and then go with that. In this case it might be best to just leave everything to Leaflet considering it has it's own API for rendering and managing interactions.

Comment: That makes sense. So your solution is to make this a "regular" javascript component, and then import it into my main component like I already do, but where the state is managed by Leaflet?

Not sure how to pass the data like that, though. How does it access `this.props.data` ?

Comment: Well that's sort of what I mean, either you need to buy into React or Leaflet. Props and state are React concepts and are mostly relevant if you are working with React components. Since you are pulling in another library which manages it's own rendering and data, if you want to pass in data from React you'd need to build some kind of 'bridge' to manage moving data between the two libraries. It sounds like a lot of trouble and I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: I actually got it working by simply re-drawing the entire Leaflet map every time new `this.props.data` is received. I'm using `componentWillReceiveProps` to check if `this.props.data` has been changed, and if, i use `clearLayers()`, and afterwards in `componentDidUpdate`, I reload everything. A bit hacky, but it works.